# Combo Charts in Google Sites using Google Sites

Tags: google-apps-script, google-visualization, google-sites

Is there a way to create Combo charts using apps script? I need to create a chart using google sites, but I havent found the way.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there are many types of charts possible via Apps Script (documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/) and a tutorial [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/charts_dashboard)), its not possible to create combo charts today.

There is already an [open request](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1931) to support this. You can follow that enhancement request for more info.

Comment: Thanks!, could you please tell me how to use this charts? And why I can't use them in google apps with HTMLService https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/combochart

Comment: Hi Arun-
Any idea what the timeline for combo charts in Apps Script is?